# Where do I report an error in googles (firebase) documentation? [Firebase setup guide]

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gradle-plugin

#### TL;DR:

Documentation use `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'` with `:`instead of `.`, resulting in crash.

---

#### Details

I found a small but time consuming error in the [Firebase setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase) and would like to fix it for future developer.

In `Step 3`, `task 2.b` under the text:

> In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), add a line to the bottom of the file.

You have the following code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

// Add the following line to the bottom of the file:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

The last line should be `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.
However, it is typed as `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'`,
with a *colon* between `com.google.gsm` and `google-services` instead of a *dot*.

This will result in the following error:

```
Initializing gradle...   
Resolving dependencies...  
* Error running Gradle: 
ProcessException: Process "/Users/me/Repos/infodisplay_flutter/android/gradlew"
exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: Build file '/Users/me/Repos/infodisplay_flutter/android/app/build.gradle' 
line: 74

* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms:google-services' not found.

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s 
Command: /Users/me/Repos/infodisplay_flutter/android/gradlew app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

The error message points to the right line but judging from other SO posts other developers have had a hard time figuring out why the plugin does not exist.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, otherwise try to make this post reach the right person(s)!

Comment: There's a "Send Feedback" button on each documentation page in the upper-right within the blue nav bar, just below your account profile photo if you're signed in.

Comment: Another way to raise *any* Google issue is go directly to the [issuetracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and press the **raise Issue** button. Then fill-in the form.

Comment: Two good suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I would say that both would be valid **answers** Mark and Jon. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my earlier comment so that this question can be marked as answered / closed -

There's a "Send Feedback" button on each documentation page in the upper-right within the blue nav bar, just below your account profile photo if you're signed in.

Jon's suggestion is also valid but I'm not sure if documentation issues have a lower priority than that of development bugs.